Python and json Highscore transferring problem
I have been making a console-based combat game in python and have recently experimented on the idea of local file persistence to store data such as highest kills in a game and highest luck (i.e., item drops) in a game. Though, when I tried doing this, a problem occurred. Whenever I loaded up the file after a game, the previous data was removed, even if it was lower than the previous bests. How do I solve this issue?
This is the data that I want to store in the JSON file:
userPreferencesAndPerformances = {
"settings": settings,
"unlockedTreasures": ["Shiny Brooch"],
"unlockedEnemies": ["Zombie"],
"highestKillCount": Kills,
"healthPotionDrops": HPotionDrops,
"strengthPotionDrops": SPotionDrops,
"criticalTokenDrops": CTokenDrops,
}

For this, I tried this:
def savePrefs(filename, data):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
def loadPrefs(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            return json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}
prefsFilename = "userPrefsNPerfs.json"
savePrefs(prefsFilename, userPreferencesAndPerformances)
loaded_prefs = loadPrefs(prefsFilename)
print("Loaded preferences:", loaded_prefs)

The issue that arose was that in the 1st game, I'd have a good score, and in the 2nd, a bad score. But the code would put the bad score in the JSON file instead as I played that game later. I want the 1st game's score to stay. By score, I implied the kills and drops.

You’ll have to read in the JSON, compare and update any fields, then write it back.

Instead of using
def savePrefs(filename, data):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

use
def savePrefs(filename, data):
    with open(filename, "a") as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

w rewrites the file, a appends to it

If I append, I only get the luxury of checking whether the new score is better than the previous one. I need to change only the singular attributes like "highestKillCount". So tell me a solution in that regard.

In addition, you can’t append to JSON because it’s a single nested structure, unless you use JSON Lines format and read and parse a single line of JSON at a time

@MarkTolonen Please elaborate how I can do this, i.e, what you stated in your comment. I am new to JSON so don't know how to do it.
